# Using two variables in validation

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I'm trying to check two variables in a validation using validate tag .Is it possible to validate two variables at the same time in pace automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

**YES** It is possible to check two variables in the validation.

```
<valGroup groupId="Check_Equals">
<validate variable="Actual_Result" condition="equals" value="${Expected_Result}" passMsg="PASSED" failMsg="FAILED" desc="VALIDATE TAG" expResult="VALIDATE the validation" >
</validate>
</valGroup>
```